# Cursor not showing up in google chrome after token is added

Tags: jquery-tokeninput

I have downloaded the zip from https://github.com/loopj/jquery-tokeninput and tried the demo.html in firefox and in chrome. In firefox after adding token cursor is being shown up:
version in 1.6.1

[image]

In **google chrome after adding token cursor is NOT being shown up**: But when we start typing cursor is shown.

[image]

I have tried the loopj version http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/demo.html given there, cursor is being shown in google chrome also.
I have looked into js file but couldn't find anything.

How to fix this issue;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Final Edit: This bug was fixed in [Pull Request #557](https://github.com/loopj/jquery-tokeninput/commit/8134937023e7949fdb946b33afda6f4ce74d5bb6).

UPDATED SOLUTION:

On line 725(ish), there is `input_box.width(0)`, in the `add_token` method. By giving the input a width of zero, the cursor is hidden from view. I've set this to `1` in my project, which allows me to now see the cursor, I'm yet to find any negative effects, and from what I can see the worst that could happen would be a slightly premature linebreak, which in my implementation I can definitely deal with!

Hope that helps!

---

ORIGINAL ANSWER: I use a different theme for this plugin in Chrome, but haven't encountered this problem. I was going to suggest posting a bug report, but I guess [this](https://github.com/loopj/jquery-tokeninput/issues/564) could be your post anyway?

Am I reading your post right that the demo's work correctly, just the file you downloaded doesn't? The Demo's run on version 1.6.0 - perhaps try replacing your .js file with that one, and see if that solves your problem as a temporary fix.

Comment: The loopJ demo version is 1.6.0 and github version is 1.6.1. The version is working perfectly. I want the github version because it has so many functionalities which i wanted and fixes also. yeah I have already raised an issue but got no reply https://github.com/loopj/jquery-tokeninput/issues/564

Comment: Fair. I have a similar issue myself, but for me, it only affects it on the posting of a certain token. (Done slightly differently to others.) I'll be working on debugging it at some point over the next few weeks, so I'll get back to you if I manage to sort it!

Comment: That would be great. Thanks Chris.

Comment: Hey chris it solved one of my problems. But when I use "add" method in jquery-tokeniput and add more than one token cursor is hiding again. I have tried to increase the width but it didn't work.

Comment: When you use the `add` method, the token goes through the same function as when they're added from the dropdown, the one we've just changed. How are you adding the tokens with the add method...I'd guess you're loosing focus on the TokenInput? Try focusing on it again with a jQuery line after adding, see if that helps.

Comment: Yeah about to comment on that. Its loosing focus. Focusing again fixed the problem. +1 for the solution. Thank you.

Comment: i am facing a similar issue, but in my case its the first time click on the input box after the tokeinput has been initialized. Now I can see that the width is set to 0 by inspecting the input_box in the chrome developer tools, but i ran through the code and couldnt find where it is doing that. can you help me out?

Comment: @MandeepJain - I would look into the resize_input method (line 559 of the current GitHub version.) Looking at it logically, I'm not sure what is going on, but I'd use the debugger to check out if your code is going through the first return statement or so. If you wanted to put up a jsfiddle with your setup, I'd be interested in taking a look!